# How to calculate or manage streaming data in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, pyspark

I wanna caculate data from streaming data and then sent to web page. **For example: I will calculate sum of TotalSales column in streaming data.** But it error at `summary = dataStream.select('TotalSales').groupby().sum().toPandas()` and this is my code.

```
import os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Python Spark SQL basic example").config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").getOrCreate()
schema = StructType().add("_c0", "integer").add("InvoiceNo", "string").add("Quantity","integer").add("InvoiceDate","date").add("UnitPrice","integer").add("CustomerID","double").add("TotalSales","integer")
INPUT_DIRECTORY = "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/test/jsonFile"
dataStream = spark.readStream.format("json").schema(schema).load(INPUT_DIRECTORY)
query = dataStream.writeStream.format("console").start()

summary = dataStream.select('TotalSales').groupby().sum().toPandas()
print(query.id)
query.awaitTermination();
```

and this is error showed on command line.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testStreaming.py", line 12, in <module>
    dataStream = dataStream.toPandas()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 2150, in toPandas
    pdf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(self.collect(), columns=self.columns)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 534, in collect
    sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 69, in deco
raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;\nFileSource[C:/Users/HP/Desktop/test/jsonFile]'
```

Thank for your answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you trying to create a a pandas Df

toPandas  will create a  DataFrame that is local to your driver node.  I am not sure what are you trying to achieve here .  Pandas DataFrame represents a fixed set of tuples, where as  structured stream  is a continuous stream  of data .

Now one possible sol to this problem is to complete the entire process that you  want to do and  send the output to a parquet/csv file  and use this parquet/csv etc  file to create a pandas DF .

```
summary = dataStream.select('TotalSales').groupby().sum()
query = dataStream.writeStream.format("parquet").outputMode("complete").start(outputPathDir)
query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: I tried your advice, It's work. I have another question. How to extract value from dataframe (summary variable). For example: I try print a summary variable. It's like this. `DataFrame[sum(TotalSales): bigint]`. I need to use value in dataframe to show on my web page.

Comment: the data as a dataframe. data in json file example: `{"InvoiceNo":"539993","CustomerID":13313.0,"TotalSales":678}
{"InvoiceNo":"539993","CustomerID":13313.0,"TotalSales":430}
{"InvoiceNo":"539993","CustomerID":13313.0,"TotalSales":350}`

Comment: If I have understood you correctly , you want to calculate the cumulative sum of the col  TotalSales. well this is a problem of multiple aggregation which unfortunately Structured streaming does not support as of now, but  u can use a work around of calculating the sum on a window or grouped on some col ,store that in a file n use Spark Sql  to calculate the total sum and display the result on the web page.